# OpenCV crash with Gaussian Blur

Tags: c++, opencv

Im trying to implement eye tracking system with OpenCV. However, when I run my code, the code crashes and the gdb debugger returns "Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)". I ran the code in debugging mode and found that somehow crash due to release function of cv::Mat in mat.inl.hpp

findEyeCenter function

```
    // ROI of eye
    cv::Mat eyeROIUnscaled = face(eye);

    // scale to fast sizse
    cv::Mat eyeROI;

    // do some operations which succeeded....
    cv::Mat weight = eyeROI.clone();
    ....
    GaussianBlur( eyeROI, weight, cv::Size_<int>( kWeightBlurSize, kWeightBlurSize ), 1 );// crash here
    ....
 }
```

Comment: Please read the 'Minimal' section of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry this was my first question on stackoverflow. Still, does anybody have an suggestion?

Comment: The problem crash happens when I call GaussianBlur from opencv. Moreover, when I try to clone the eyeROI to weight Mat, it crashes.